# Reemplazar filas acorde con un criterio

Tags: r

Me gustaría encontrar una forma más simple para realizar este script.
 Tengo un dataframe:

```
      ClearDatos<-Datraframe

 species level:
 Site      Date    Habitat    Season    Year     Taxa
 Q1F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Adonis_flammea
 Q2F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Agrimonia_eupatoria
 Q4F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Ajuga_chamaepitys
 Q1P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Ajuga
 Q2P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Allium_sativum
```

Quiero remplazar los nombres de la columna taxa, que lo compone un género_especie, por solo géneros. 
Hasta ahora lo hacía individuo por individuo cambiándolas.

```
 ClearDatos$Taxa<-gsub("Adonis_flammea","Adonis",ClearDatos$Taxa)
 ClearDatos$Taxa<-gsub("Agrimonia_eupatoria","Agrimonia",ClearDatos$Taxa)
 ClearDatos$Taxa<-gsub("Ajuga_chamaepitys","Ajuga",ClearDatos$Taxa)
 ClearDatos$Taxa<-gsub("Allium_sativum","Allium",ClearDatos$Taxa)
```

Obteniendo estos resultados:

```
 species level:
 Site      Date    Habitat    Season    Year     Taxa
 Q1F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Adonis
 Q2F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Agrimonia
 Q4F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Ajuga
 Q1P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Ajuga
 Q2P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Allium
```

¿Existe una forma más rápida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad lo que buscas es substituir un valor por otro y no necesitarías usar `gsub` por lo que puedes armar un `data.frame` de valores de reemplazo de manera que sea un poco más sencillo. Voy a usar los datos de tu anterior pregunta a modo de ejemplo:

```
Specieslevel <- read.table(text="Site Date Habitat Season Year Taxa
Q1F 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Artemisia_herba_alta
Q2F 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Artemisia_herba_alta
Q4F 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Allium
Q1P 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Artemisia_herba_alta
Q2P 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Amaranthus
Q4P 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Anacyclus
Q4P 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Asparagus
Q4P 08_09_2015 Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Amaranthus_retroflex", sep=" ", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

species = data.frame(value     = c('Artemisia_herba_alta', 'Amaranthus_retroflex'), 
                     replaceby = c('Artemisia', 'Amaranthus'),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

matches <- match(Specieslevel$Taxa, species$value, nomatch=0)
Specieslevel$Taxa[matches>0] <- species$replaceby[matches] 
Specieslevel
```

El resultado final:

```
  Site       Date Habitat Season      Year       Taxa
1  Q1F 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016  Artemisia
2  Q2F 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016  Artemisia
3  Q4F 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016     Allium
4  Q1P 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016  Artemisia
5  Q2P 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Amaranthus
6  Q4P 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016  Anacyclus
7  Q4P 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016  Asparagus
8  Q4P 08_09_2015     Oak Autumn 2015-2016 Amaranthus
```

Explicación:

- Creamos un `data.frame` `species` que va a contener los valores de búsqueda y  reemplazo. Debiera funcionar también si las variables son factores. Lo defino como `data.frame` para que el código sea más legible, pero eventualmente podría ser una matriz para escribir un poco menos.
- Con `match(Specieslevel$Taxa, species$value, nomatch=0)` obtenemos un vector del tamaño de `Specieslevel` dónde tendremos la fila del dato de reemplazo o `0` en caso de no coincidencia
- Aplicamos estos `matches` reemplazando solo aquellos que correspondan: `Specieslevel$Taxa[matches>0] <- species$replaceby[matches]`

**¿Que ocurre si lo que queremos modificar del `dataframe`es un `Factor`?**, bueno, el código anterior no sirve ya que en el mismo operamos sobre la columna completa, y ahora solo deberías trabajar sobre los `levels`. La solución es incluso más sencilla y rápida:

```
sp <- levels(Specieslevel$Taxa)
matches <- match(sp, species$value, nomatch=0) 
sp[matches>0] <- species$replaceby[matches] 
levels(Specieslevel$Taxa) <- sp
```

En este caso creamos primero un vector de los `levels` de la columna (`sp <- levels(Specieslevel$Taxa)`) y el `match` y `replace` lo hacemos sobre este. Luego lo que nos falta es redefinir los `levels` de la columna haciendo `levels(Specieslevel$Taxa) <- sp`

Comment: Sin palabras Patricio, funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Patricio, gracias por tu pronta respuesta. El script funciona. El problema es que lo sustituye por un valor N/A ¿Cómo podría corregirlo?

Comment: @AdriánP.L. Lo que ocurre es que seguramente en tu caso `Specieslevel$Taxa` es un factor (en mi ejemplo no) y no una cadena común, por lo que en el `match` hay que convertir la columna así: `matches <- match(as.character(Specieslevel$Taxa), species$value, nomatch=0)`

Comment: el script que me has pasado funciona, pero ahora cuando intento correr el siguiente;                                                                                                                                                         Specieslevel$Taxa[matches>0] <- species$replaceby[matches] me aparece este mensaje Warning message:  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, matches > 0, value = c(29L, 29L, 29L, 29L,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @AdriánP.L., si en el caso de los `Factor` hay que hacer algo un poco distinto, revisa mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: perdona Patricio... tras la última edición el script corre (a pesar de sustituir un par de veces species por sp) pero se borra por completo la columna de taxa, justamente cuando ejecuto la última linea del script; levels(Specieslevel$Taxa) <- sp ¿necesita alguna última correción? Muchas gracias y disculpa las molestias

Comment: @AdriánP.L., no tienes que sustituir nada, `sp` es una nueva variable que tuve que agregar. El código que agregué para el tratamiento de los factores reemplaza completamente las últimas tres lineas del código anterior, lo demás sigue igual. Avisame cualquier cosa.

Comment: Patricio, ¡funciona correctamente! mi problema es que las especies que sustituía bajo el nombre de sp en vez de species por eso no me concordaba antes. Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda